# CheckBox covers text in GridView

Tags: android, checkbox, android-layout

I'm pretty new to Android, and I'm looking for a little help.
I have a GridView with the following XML in a linear layout.

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

I'm adding a series of CheckBoxes to the view with...

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CheckBox checkView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            checkView = new CheckBox(context);
            checkView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        } else {
            checkView = (CheckBox) convertView;
        }
        checkView.setText(checkNames[position]);
        checkView.setWidth(400);

        return checkView;
    }
```

No matter how many different widths I try, including fill_parent and
wrap_content, the text winds up behind the box instead of next to it.
Any hints or tricks?
Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Any body have anything? I will add that I adding the views through a View Adapter if that gives any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using only wrap content for both layout width and layout height. Because the fill_parent will fill the full layout, where as wrap_content will fill only to the size of your text entered.

Comment: Fill parent to the grid view or to the check boxes?

Comment: Still haven't been able to make this work. The only way I've been able to get the text out from behind the check box is to change the gravity, and that doesn't look right when I rotate the screen. I have yet to find another setting that moves it. Anyone?

Comment: Also, since gravity fixes the problem, it suggests that the element is wide enough, but the text is just displaying in the wrong position.